# Minimal setup to use vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver, vapor/fluent in a standalone Swift package?

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

What is the minimal code setup needed to use [vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver) or [vapor/fluent](https://github.com/vapor/fluent) in a standalone Swift executable package?  "Standalone" meaning without the inclusion of Vapor itself.

Basically, what would "Hello World" starters look like for a FluentSQLiteDriver (SQL-like calls) standalone executable package and Fluent (ORM calls) standalone executable package?

Background:

I set out to create two quick & simple packages to tinker with "`fluent-sqlite-driver`" and  "`fluent` + `fluent-sqlite-driver`".  Alas, "quick" did not happen and "simple" remains TBD. Some of the findings:

1. "The package readmes will show docs on how to use the package standalone" did not happen for [Fluent](https://github.com/vapor/fluent) and for the related [FluentSQLiteDriver](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver)...

- ["[Docs] Better explanation of how to set up Fluent without Vapor infrastructure #583"](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/issues/583)

2. "... a great reference for seeing how to configure Fluent without Vapor. [For example: FluentSQLiteDriverTests.swift](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite-driver/blob/master/Tests/FluentSQLiteDriverTests/FluentSQLiteDriverTests.swift#L183-L188%22)" leads one on a nugget treasure explorering the depths of things like `FluentBenchmark`. Not so simple.